# ~/.profile not reloading

Tags: command-line, bash, .profile, source

- I am using Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
- Wanted to know why changes are not reflected 
     when I change
  the `~/.profile` and reloading the file using
  `source  ~/.profile` or `. ~/.profile`
  The changes are only reflected after restart

example:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/mypc/tools/node/node-v14.17.1-linux-x64/bin
#export PATH=$PATH:/home/mypc/tools/node/node-v10.24.1-linux-x64/bin
```

after commenting the one node path and running source ~/.profile
the current termial still loads the commented one.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your commands **append** stuff to the current path. But path resolution happens from left to right, so what you append probably makes no difference.

When you restart, you erase your current `$PATH` value.

Comment: I missed # in the 2nd line. if second path or 1st line is commented. after source ~/.profile the uncommented path should be effective ?

Comment: @Hexgear Doesn't matter. `:` appends. Try `PATH=/home/mypc/whatever` or `PATH=/home/whatever:$PATH` instead.

Comment: thanks it worked. could you please enlighten me with this how path is resolved in linux?
As I run echo $PATH I can see the commented path are also present